# YouTube API + PHP + site hosting?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework, youtube-api

I have made a site which can pull and upload videos from and to YouTube,
http://www.tole-rants.com/

This site was made with the combination of Python, Google App Engine and YouTube API. It is hosted at Google App Engine. I did not code the main structure of this application bcos I don't speak Python so I was made with a Python programmer. However, we found that this application has been causing lot of problems, especially on uploading videos.

Now I hope I can code the entire site myself with PHP - is it possible?

Another big question - do I have to host this site on Google's?? Can I just host this site on a normal/ standard server which I normally do when I develop a website?

I have read the documentation about YouTube API for developers, but I still cannot get my head around if I want to make this site from scratch with PHP.

It seems to suggest that using a PHP framework - Zend Framework, which I have no clues about it - do I really have to use a PHP framework then?

Any thoughts/ better suggestions or any online tutorials/ books I can follow through?

Many thanks,
Lau

Comment: Your site is amazing..!! :-)
First confirm if the problems caused are due to programming problems or due to google app engine..?
Besides, i'll suggest going for google web toolkit and and its youtube api - code.google.com/p/gwt-youtube-api/ This will lead to a tighter integration. Btw, I would like to ask you something. Is the bandwidth required to show youtube videos, deducted from your app engine limit, or is it directly hosted by youtube...??

Comment: What makes you think that rewriting your site in PHP will solve these (unspecified) problems?

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to host it on Google's. You can host it anywhere. And you don't need to use the Zend Framework. What they are suggesting is that you use the Zend framework's GData library to communicate with YouTube API. But you wouldnt even need that. YouTube Data API documentation is complete with examples. I am sure it will help you. But ofcourse if you have some specific questions you can ask them here.

Comment: hi glad to know that! thanks so much for the reply.

the specific thing which I do need is to know how to upload video to my YouTube account if I am using PHP to communicate with YouTube API.

did anyone raise such a question here before? if someone did - do u know any threads I can trace back?

thanks!

Comment: And this here has so many examples in PHP, so do have a look, there is code here for uploading videos to youtube account:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Uploading_Videos